# how to Extract a Field from a line wit tab delimer in java

Tags: java, c++

I have a `c++` method `extractField` that I would like to use to `axtract` some fields from a line each field delimited by `'\t'` it works well in `c++` could someone help me with the syntax for java. I would like to apply a similler `method_ here` is what I have:

```
    String ExtractField(String aline,int fieldnumber){
    Int seppos;
    String field;
    for (int fld = 0: fld< fieldnumber;fld++){
      seppos = aline.Pos('\t');
      field = aline.SubString(1,seppos-1);
      aline.delete(1.seppos);
    }
     If(seppos>0){return field;}
     else{return aline;}
    }
```

Comment: My C++ is not good enough to follow what exactly you are doing, but you can use `String foo; foo.split('\t');` to split apart tab separated values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will do what you want.

```
public String extractField(String aline, int fieldNumber) {
    String[] fields = aline.split("\t");
    //Illegal field NUmber.
    if (fieldNumber < 0 || fieldNumber >= fields.length) {
        return null;
    }
    return fields[fieldNumber];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The folowing is in java, rewrote it for you ;)

```
private String ExtractField(String aline, int fieldnumber)
{
    Integer seppos = new Integer();
    String field;
    for (int fld = 0; fld < fieldnumber; fld++)
    {
      seppos = aline.indexOf('\t');
      field = aline.substring(1, seppos - 1);
      //aline.delete(1.seppos); what does this do?
    }
     If(seppos > 0)
     {
         return field;
     }
     else
     {
         return aline;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use StringTokenizer

```
 StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(aline, "\t");
 while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
     System.out.println(st.nextToken());
 }
```